# How can I add services after build IServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, ioc-container

These are some definitions:

```cs
public interface IClassA
{
    
}
```

```cs
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ClassB
{
    private IClassA _classA;
    public ClassB(IClassA classA)
    {
        this._classA = classA;
    }
}
```

If I build the service provider, the singleton instance will be created twice or more after I add more serivces into the ioc container and get them.

```cs
IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<IClassA,ClassA>();
ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IClassA>();


serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<ClassB>();
serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClassB>();
```

The output is:

```
Hello!!!
Hello!!!
```

It means the instance ClassA has been created twice.
I want to use the ServiceProvider after I add some services into the ioc container at the stage one. I want to add some services into the container at the stage two and get some services.
However, how can I make sure the service that is singleton will be created once still after I get my services at stage two.

Comment: Building the provider twice like that is usually considered a bad practice. Can you elaborate _why_ you need to do this in the first place? It's very possible that it can be achieved without 2 distinct providers.

Comment: @julealgon Thank you, I have redesigned my project after seeing this comment. And I find it is not necessary to add more services after build the serviceProvider. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each `IServiceProvider` keeps track of its own services separately, using the approach of registering the type will not work properly as each provider will end up instantiating the singleton, leading to 2 distinct instances as you saw.

If you really want to have 2 providers (a bad idea in general), you *could* workaround this problem by passing the instance to the container:

```
var classA = new ClassA();
IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IClassA>(classA);
ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IClassA>();


serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<ClassB>();
serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClassB>();
```

When resolving anything from either provider, it will not attempt to instantiate the type since you are providing the instance explicitly.

This is however a fairly hacky approach and I would not recommend it unless it really was your last option.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to also add the instance of ClassA as the parameter for the constructor of ClassB, to ensure that it is the same instance used on both services?

Although, this is some unholy messy process to do. I would not recommend doing this ever. 

One serviceCollection for all your needs, is cleaner, neater, and a lot less prone to "wtf's" but other programmers.
Plus aren't you just overloading the originally created serviceProvider on the second build?

Comment: _"Wouldn't you need to also add the instance of ClassA as the parameter for the constructor of ClassB, to ensure that it is the same instance used on both services?"_ not really @MortenBork. Since the instance is being registered against the `IClassA` interface, resolving it with that interface will ensure the same instance is used everywhere. The services before the first `BuildServiceProvider` call remain in the same collection and will be part of the second provider as well.

Comment: _"Plus aren't you just overloading the originally created serviceProvider on the second build?"_ Not exactly sure what you mean by this @MortenBork but in the event that you re-register something in the second build, it would look different in the second container. Notice that whatever happens to the `IServiceCollection` after the `IServiceProvider` has been built will have zero effect on the provider: the registrations are taken as input and "stored" inside the provider, so they cannot be changed after the fact.

Comment: in the 

ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

You declare it.

In the: serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

You overload it, no?

Comment: @MortenBork ah that's what you mean... the same variable is reused, so the previous provider is "gone" at that point (unless it was passed around somewhere). Whatever service it resolved is still there though.